# Where to find list of development packages to build evolution on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, evolution, fedora

I am trying to build latest version of Evolution on my Ubuntu using guides provided on this page: [Building Evolution from sources](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/Building)  but the guide is written for fedora and it lists some packages that must be installed before build. But those packages are for fedora and I need equivalent packages on Ubuntu.

Any one could help me to find equivalent packages on Ubuntu for following Fedora packages:

```
    gcr-devel
    glib2-devel
    gnome-online-accounts-devel
    gobject-introspection-devel
    gtk3-devel
    json-glib-devel
    krb5-devel
    libgdata-devel
    libgweather-devel
    libical-devel
    libsecret-devel
    libxml2-devel
    nspr-devel
    nss-devel
    openldap-devel
    sqlite-devel
    webkitgtk4-devel
```

Comment: packages.ubuntu.com (eg. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=glib2)  can be useful; many will just need -devel replaced with -dev, but Ubuntu will use upstream debian names.  If you prefer terminal (faster too), use `apt-cache search`  (eg. `apt-cache search gcr-`)

Answer (score 0):

The special `apt-get` subcommand exists for such purpose - it is called `build-dep`.

See `man apt-get` [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) or from your system:

> **build-dep**
>    `build-dep` causes apt-get to install/remove packages in an attempt to satisfy the build dependencies for a source package. By default the dependencies are satisfied to build the package natively. If desired a host-architecture can be specified with the         `--host-architecture` option instead.

So you have to use it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep evolution
```

If you want only to view them - then use `--simulate`:

```
apt-get build-dep --simulate evolution
```